# setLogo toolbar from url pictures

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I need to insert a sort of Logo in toolbar:

this is code:

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(titolo);
    toolbar.setLogo(*);
```

*here i need to insert logo from url. Is this possible?

EDIT:

this is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

I can't insert ImageView in this toolbar.
How can i create imageview in this xml?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

in java

```
ImageView logo= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
 Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(url)
    .crossFade()
    .into(logo);
```

[image]

Comment: and next is `toolbar.setLogo(myImageView)` ?

Comment: @francescobocci above code was just an example you have to pass your logo url in 'load' method of Glide to load the image from url. Glide will download the image and then set it to your myImageView

Comment: see my edit.. when i insert "imageview" into my xml I don't see him in androidstudio preview.. infact when i use your code they don't do nothing

Comment: @francescobocci please give me some time, let me make that code working for you with proper code

Comment: @francescobocci i have edited my code and also have attached a screenshot. i this i have set image from drawable . but as you want load image form url you can use Glide as i have mentioned in my answer. this will load image from url in imageview

Answer (score -1):

`toolbar.setLogo` only accepts drawable. It will not accept a URL. So while there is a workaround to insert an `imageview` into toolbar to load the image using Glide/Picasso, that is not equivalent to setting the logo.
In order to set the logo from a URL, you will have to create a Drawable resource from a URL. Code below

```
public static Drawable drawableFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
Bitmap x;

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
return new BitmapDrawable(x); 
}
```

then you can insert this drawable into the logo. Code below:

```
Drawable thisDrawable = drawableFromUrl(url);
toolbar.setLogo(thisDrawable);
```

This should meet your objective. Let me know how it goes.. All the best!!